Is it safe to convert a R-12 AC manifold gauge set to recharge a R-134a system?
I found an AC manifold gauge set lying around the house. My vehicle's AC is not as cold as it was in the past. I wanted to recharge the vehicle's AC. I noticed my manifold gauge set's high and low sides did not fit the vehicle's high and low side ports (the car uses r-134a refrigerant). So I bought adapters for the high and low side ports

I ran into a problem with the supply hose. The threads on R-134a refrigerant container won't go into the R12 yellow supply hose. (shown below)

Do I simply buy an adapter like the one in the picture below and go merrily charging my R-134a system afterward? Is it safe to convert an R-12 AC manifold gauge set to recharge an R-134a system?


Yes, use the brass adapter for the yellow hose (allows threading male 1/4 pipe  threads into the yellow hose while allowing r134a ACME threads to screw on to the can adapter. I don't know if its a no-no to reusing r12 gauge/hose sets since there are no markings for r134a on both gauges, requiring you to use gauges for pressure only. You can always replace gauges labeled for r134a if you use this set often. Examine the replaceable rubber bushings on hose ends and replace them before use. I replaced my reliable r12 gauge set with new and getting adapters for r134a use. In the end, they pay for themselves the first time they're used.
